# How to disable word selection on double click?

Tags: emacs

I want to bind `jump to definition` function to double click. Unfortunately this screws up with default emacs behavior, which is `select a word under the click point`. How can I disable it?

Comment: I removed the sample answer because it relies upon code in Emacs Trunk, which is unfortunately not presently available in the most recent public release of Emacs.  I do not anticipate having an opportunity today to come up with an alternative version that is backwards compatible -- sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Actually it didn't work even in trunk :)

Comment: `(mouse-set-region event)` is likely what you are looking to replace.  In the most recent public release, it is *not* contained within `mouse-set-point`, but rather buried within `mouse-drag-track` which is called by `mouse-drag-region`.  You likely will want to replace `(mouse-set-region event)` with your custom function - perhaps defining a new `mouse-drag-region` and a new `mouse-drag-track`.  In my Emacs Trunk from October 1, 2014, `(mouse-set-region event)` is closer to the surface -- i.e., right there under `mouse-set-point`.  I don't have a more recent Emacs Trunk built at this time.